# Problems loading a second advertisement from a different ad unit path

Tags: google-ad-manager

Original title: can't get second ad to load - CORS error?

I have a page that should serve two ads, set up with Google Ad Manager.

The first one works.  The second one doesn't load. Ever. Here's what's in the google ads console:
Leaderboard-Bottom: Ad unit did not fetch.

And in dev tools console:
cess to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?pvsid=103533111800458&correlator=3920814372287942&eid=31074438&output=ldjh&gdfp_req=1&vrg=202305040101&ptt=17&impl=fif&iu_parts=40687709%2CLeaderboard-Bottom...' from origin 'https://' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here's my code:
In head:

```
<script>

<!-- Start GPT Tag -->
  window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    
    var mapping1 = googletag.sizeMapping()
                            .addSize([1024, 400], [[970, 90], [728, 90]])
                            .addSize([768, 400], [[728, 90]])
                            .addSize([470, 400], [[320, 50], [300, 250], [320, 100]])
                            .addSize([360, 400], [[300, 250]])
                            .addSize([0, 0], [[300, 250]])
                            .build();
      
    googletag.defineSlot('/40687709/Leaderboard-Bottom', [[300, 250], [336,280], [468, 60], [728, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-1683653030167-0')
             .defineSizeMapping(mapping1)
             .addService(googletag.pubads());     
      
    googletag.defineSlot('/41382309/Leaderboard-Top', [[300, 250], [336,280], [468, 60], [728, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-1683643992415-0')
             .defineSizeMapping(mapping1)
             .addService(googletag.pubads()); 
      

     googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest(); 
    googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
             
    googletag.enableServices();
      
  });
</script>
```

In the body - first ad (that works)

```
    <div class="top-leader">
<!-- /41382309/Leaderboard-Top -->
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1683643992415-0' >
  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1683643992415-0'); });
  </script>
</div>

    </div>
```

Second ad (broken)

```
  <div class="bottom-leader">

    <!-- /41382309/Leaderboard-Bottom -->
    <div id='div-gpt-ad-1683653030167-0' >
      <script>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1683653030167-0'); });
      </script>
    </div>

  </div>
```

UPDATE:  I've partially fixed my problem. The problem seems to result from trying to call defineSlot from two different ad unit paths.  When I call it with the same ad unit path, my second and third (not shown) ads load.  I'm not sure why this is a problem.  The documentation doesn't mention it. https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/guides/get-started#ad-unit-path ?

Comment: Based on your Update : has your second ad unit been created and activated in the GAM user interface ?